# Heat produced by resistor in a circuit with charged capacitor and no battery

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, capacitance

C2 has a charge of 8C and 4F capacitance. C3 has no charge and 2F capacitance. S2 is then closed for a long time.
What is the total Joule heat generated in resistor R2?

[image]

The answer is 8J/3 but I'm not sure how to get to this.

What I was asked to do before I got to this question:

- Find the charge stored in C3 after S2 is closed for a long time. (8C/3. Confirmed answer.)
- Find the total energy stored in C2 and C3. (16C/3. Confirmed answer)
- 

What I did to solve the problem:

E=VQ

The total voltage across both capacitors when S2 has closed for a long time is 8/3 (using C=Q/V on both capacitors), and the amount of charge that moved from C2 to C3 was 8/3, so E = 64/9.

I also tried just using the initial conditions of C2, so V = 2, Q = 8, and E = 16.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initial voltage on $C_2$ is q/C = 2 volts.  After the switch is closed, the charge of 8 C from the + plate of $C_2$ must be shared with the + plate of $C_3$ with $C_2$ having twice as much as $C_3$.  This puts 8/3 C on $C_3$ and 16/3 C on $C_2$, and each at a voltage of 4/3 v. You need to calculate the loss of energy from before to after.